# How do I ignore a field size in a struct using Marshal.SizeOf?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, sizeof

Is there a way to ignore a field in the calculated of the struct size using Marshal.SizeOf

Ex:

```
public struct Message
{
   public ushort X;
   public ushort Y; // Ignore this field in the calculation
}

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Message));
```

Right now size is 4.  I want the size to be 2.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A union would be if i explicitly set the field offsets to be the same (C# does have unions), I dont want to do that.

Comment: I think you have to explain why you want this in order for us to help you. If all you want is to have it be "2", then why not replace it with a literal 2? Or just pass typeof(ushort) to the marshal.sizeof() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing it would be to create a [Custom Marshaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3cxf9f0(VS.80).aspx) and when you implement [ICustomMarshaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler(VS.80).aspx).[GetNativeDataSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler.getnativedatasize(VS.80).aspx), return 0.  You would use [MarshalAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) to apply the custom marshaller to just that field.  But, it won't marshal properly, so I don't know why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. Why would you want to do that?